# In a opencv canny image output, how can I join the missing part of the line which will result into a square which I want to find in the findContours?

Tags: python, opencv, contour, canny-operator

My canny output looks like below:

original canny output of the image:

[image: original canny output of the image]

In the image I want to join the line as shown below which basically completes the shape:

The desired output image:

[image: The desired output image]

Comment: Please show your code and original input image. That way others can test your code and concepts. You may be better off using thresholding and contours than Canny.  Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Find the four corners and then fit a quadrilateral or join the corners with four lines.